# git change branches with some files being modified

Tags: git

I'm working on the branch 'br3'. I have 3 modified files. I want to commit them to different branch, for example 'br1'. I know that I can safely change branches only if I don't have modified files in the tree, so I need to either:

- copy files, revert changes, change branch, paste files
- stash files, change branch, unstash them

I've never tried second option and I'm not sure it will work out. Will it? Or there is better alternative to the ones I outlined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a so-called "merge checkout" which will attempt to merge any changes you have made in the working tree into the target branch.

```
git checkout --merge br1
```

If there are any conflicts then you will have to resolve them just as when merging branches.

I would strongly suggest running `git stash && git stash apply` first, as this will make sure that you can return the working directory to its current state in case the merge fails so badly that you have to reset.  If this happens and you did stash your changes, you can restore the working directory like this, and then try again:

```
git reset --hard
git checkout br3
git stash apply
```

Comment: Will it try to merge only modified files?

Comment: @Maximus That doesn't really matter.  Merging two identical files is a no-op, so even if Git tried the end result would be the same: the files would still be identical.

Comment: If you run git stash first, then there isn't going to be anything to merge unless you reapply them

Comment: @cdhowie, br1 and br3 have a lot of differences in files. However, I want to merge only differences of only those files, that are now determined as modified. I don't want to merge entire branches. Is that what it's going to do?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, according to the documentation.  *"However, with this option, a three-way merge between the current branch, your working tree contents, and the new branch is done, and you will be on the new branch."*

Answer (score 3):

> I know that I can safely change branches only if I don't have modified files in the tree,

That's not really true; if the changes will apply cleanly, it will work fine.  If not, you'll be told so and given the chance to fix them.

Your second option is probably the safest:

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout br1
$ git stash apply
$ git add ...
$ git commit ...
```

But it's quite likely that just:

```
$ git checkout br1
$ git add ... 
$ git commit ...
```

will work just fine.

Comment: *"If the changes will apply cleanly"* <-- I don't think this is technically true.  IIRC, you can only switch branches with a dirty working directory when all of the dirty files in the working directory are **identical** in the current and target commit.

Comment: @cdhowie - that could be, yeah.

Comment: @cdhowie, >> _are identical in the current and target commit_ --could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Maximus I'm not sure how I can elaborate, unless you are not clear on what "current commit" and "target commit" mean.  "Current commit" is the commit you have checked out currently.  "Target commit" is the commit you are trying to check out.

Answer (score 1):

Stashing and applying is one solution

```
git stash
git checkout TARGET_BRANCH
git apply
#review and if i like it
git stash drop
```

Read more about it here: 
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Another is diff based, perhaps the other branch you already have open in another repo (stashes don't go from repo to repo). Or perhaps even on a different box!

```
git diff HEAD > ~/mypatch
cd SOME_OTHER_REPO 
#(or mail it to the other box or what have you and extract to ~/mypatch)
git checkout other_branch
git apply ~/mypatch
```